# Where is the place to put the classes that are not part of Entity Model?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, project, projects-and-solutions

If you need to create some classes that are not part of the Entity Model (For example some method objects, some other immutable objects etc.)

- How are those type of classes named -as they are not part of Entity Model?
- Where is the place (the folder name or?) to put such classes in your Project?

Comment: 1. Why these classes should be specially named? 2. It depends on what these classes are, and how is your solution structured. Anyway, it is hard to answer - your question is too abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what those classes are for, you can create a folder named `Infrastructure` or `Helpers` or `Extensions`.

Answer (score -2):

I would just put it on the App_Code folder or just a create a brand new class file like "class1.cs" like any other class and add it to the project and set the appropriate namespaces and everything.